# Incenters Q,R,S are collinear then D and incenters P,Q,R are lie on a circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a right-angled triangle with $\widehat{B}=90^\circ$ and let $BD$ be the altitude from $B$ on
to $AC$. Draw $DE\perp AB$ and $DF\perp BC$. Let $P, Q, R$ and $S$ be respectively the incentres of
triangle $DFC$, $DBF$, $DEB$ and $DAE$. Suppose $S, R, Q$ are collinear. Prove that $P, Q, R,
D$ lie on a circle.

[image]

Comment: Please improve formatting and add some context/attempts.

Comment: $ADB$ and $BDC$ map to each other through a spiral similarity centered at $D$. This allows to perform some angle chasing.

Comment: In particular, in the given configuration $\widehat{SDQ},\widehat{RDQ}$ and $\widehat{PQR}$ all are right angles.

Comment: I tried to use coordinate geometry by assuming angle A as and hyp to be fixed which are general property of any triangle. Hyp is divided in k:1 ratio,  finding all points and incenters by incenter formula we get all points. Then prove what is required is possible but Is too lengthy. Want to use geometry please help

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, a [spiral similarity](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/GeoGebra/SpiralSimilarityAndCollinearity.shtml) around $D$ maps $ADB$ into $BDC$, hence $\widehat{RDP}$ is surely a right angle. In order to prove the statement, it is enough to show that $\widehat{PQR}=\widehat{PQS}$ is a right angle too. On the other hand the previous spiral similarity brings $S$ into $Q$  and $R$ into $P$ by rotating around $D$ by $90^\circ$ counterclockwise, then applying a suitable dilation. It follows that the $SR$ line is orthogonal to the $QP$ line and we are done: $PR$ is a diameter of the circumcircle of $PQRD$.